# jQuery / ie6 - Need some help with file upload in ie6

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6

Im having a bit of a problem with an application im writing.

Basically im using jquery to replace the normal html 'browse' button, then when someone chooses a file, it displays it in a  next to the new upload button.

I have tested this all around and it works perfect ... except for f$*king ie6.

I wouldnt care too much except my client works in a corporate environment that doesnt want to spend the time or money coming out of the stone ages.

I really need a workaround to get this going in ie6 aswell.

When you click the new button, the 'browse' dialog appears, except everything after that doesnt work and when clicking on the update button it doesnt upload the file.

Im not good working with ie6 bugs, so i wouldnt know where to begin.

The code that i have for the jQuery and also the  and input dialog are as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clickFileUpload() {
        $('.chart').trigger('click');
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".chart").change(function (){
            var fileName = $(this).val();
            $(".filename").html(fileName);
        });
    });
</script>

<p class="box"><a href="#" onclick="clickFileUpload();" class="btn"><span class="icon icon-add">&nbsp;</span>Upload Chart</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="filename">No file chosen</span><input class="chart" name="chart" style="visibility: hidden;" type="file"></p>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say for sure, but there is a good chance this may not be a bug, but a security restriction. Due to the age and known security problems of IE6, MS did change things concerning file inputs, so that it's possibly more strict than newer versions.

My suggestion: Don't try to style, script or otherwise mess with file inputs. The restrictions  are there for a reason. The designer in you may not like it, but it avoids other future problems due to different or changing restrictions in all browsers.

If you really need to do this, then there are ready made scripts for this, however I never used them and can't say if they work with IE6. Also there are Flash and Java applet workarounds, too.